# Borrar credenciales de Git en el visual studio Code

Tags: git, vscode

Tengo un problema con mi `visual code` al momento de hacer commit en mi repositorio.

Cuando hago `commit`, ese `commit` queda con la cuenta personal , debería de quedar con mi cuenta empresarial, desinstale el `visual code` , `node js`, `git`, elimine mi cuenta empresarial del proyecto para que no tenga permisos, pero aun así al momento de clonar el proyecto y realizar `commit` me sigue quedando con la cuenta personal.

Es muy raro por que no tengo permisos para el proyecto.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de eliminar las credenciales de `git` en `visual code`,  para así volver a ingresarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que el nombre de los commits se configura localmente, que es diferente de los permisos que tiene una persona para un proyecto.

Intenta cambiando tu email y nombre de esta manera:

```
git config --global user.name "NOMBRE"

git config --global user.email "CORREO@example.com"
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a  realizar el cambio y te cuento